# Determining if a service (e.g. HTTPD) is available/running on WinCE

Tags: windows-ce

I have got a device running WinCE and the SDK for developing applications for it.

Is it possible to know whether httpd is running/available in the WinCE running on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  If the device has a console and command line processor as part of the OS, just use

`services list`

If you don't have a console, use a registry editor (Remote Registry Editor for example) to look in the registry under

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services]`

**EDIT**

I suppose I forgot the other (fairly obvious) option of programmatically querying for it with the[`EnumServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450368.aspx) API call.